# Show/Hide Canvas using radio button

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm new to Javascript and Canvas, there's a lot of resources I've used and now I got confused. I'm doing a dress customization using Canvas.
This is my HTML:

```
 //these are my button samples
<input type="radio" id="shape1" name="round" onchange="display()" /> 
<input type="radio" id="shape2" name="box" onchange="display()" />

// this is where I'll display the canvas
<canvas id="displaycanvas" height="450px" width="820px" style="position:absolute;"> </canvas>
```

So for my Javascript I have this:

```
  function display() { 
    if (document.getElementById('shape1').checked) {
      var canvasC = document.getElementById('displaycanvas'),
          context = canvasC.getContext('2d');
           context.beginPath();
           context.arc(95,50,40,0,2*Math.PI);
           context.stroke();     }

    if (document.getElementById('shape2').checked) {
      var canvasR = document.getElementById('displaycanvas'),
          context = canvasR.getContext('2d');
            context.beginPath();
            context.rect(50, 27, 350, 400);    }
}
```

They are all working fine, it displays the shapes if I choose one of these buttons. My concern is how do I display only **1 shape** at a time.

I'm not sure if toggle was the right thing, please tell me what is the right thing to do.  Thank you very much in advance,

Comment: Sorry for the mistake in Name, I've made them the same Name="shape",  it was supposed to be in value that's why they are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the radios the same name to toggle them and you need to clear the canvas too.

I have used the same name for the canvas now

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelector("#shape1").onclick = document.querySelector("#shape2").onclick = function() {
    var canvas = document.querySelector('#displaycanvas');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    context.beginPath();
    if (this.id == "shape1") {
      context.arc(95, 50, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    } else {
      context.rect(50, 27, 350, 400);
    }
    context.stroke();
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="shape1" name="shape" value="round" />
<input type="radio" id="shape2" name="shape" value="box" />
<canvas id="displaycanvas" height="450px" width="820px" style="position:absolute;"></canvas>
```

If you want TWO canvases, you can do

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelector("#shape1").onclick = function() {
    document.querySelector('#displaycanvas1').style.display="";
    document.querySelector('#displaycanvas2').style.display="none";
  }
  document.querySelector("#shape2").onclick = function() {
    document.querySelector('#displaycanvas2').style.display="";
    document.querySelector('#displaycanvas1').style.display="none";
  }
}
```

still giving the radios the same name

Comment: sorry, i checked everyone's answert. I thought it will still be counted. I rechecked again yours and yes you were the first one and its correct. my bad and thanks for notifying me.

Comment: Thanks - no problem

Answer (score 1):

If the radio buttons have the same `name` attribute, they will alternate between the available ones. If they have different `name` attributes, they will be grouped separately.

```js
function display() {
  var s1 = document.querySelector('#shape1').checked,
      s2 = document.querySelector('#shape2').checked;
  alert("shape1: " + s1 + ", shape2: " + s2)
}

function display2() {
  var s3 = document.querySelector('#shape3').checked,
      s4 = document.querySelector('#shape4').checked;
  alert("shape3: " + s3 + ", shape4: " + s4)
}
```

```html
1-2
<input type="radio" name="shape" value="shape1" id="shape1" onclick="display()" />
<input type="radio" name="shape" value="shape2" id="shape2" onclick="display()" />

<br /><br />

3-4
<input type="radio" name="round" value="shape3" id="shape3" onclick="display2()" />
<input type="radio" name="square" value="shape4" id="shape4" onclick="display2()" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code to achieve your requirement:

```js
function display() { 
 var canvasC = document.getElementById('displaycanvas');
 context = canvasC.getContext('2d');
 context.clearRect(0, 0, canvasC.width, canvasC.height);
    if (document.getElementById('shape1').checked) {
           context.beginPath();
           context.arc(95,50,40,0,2*Math.PI);
           context.stroke();     }

    if (document.getElementById('shape2').checked) {
            context.beginPath();
            context.rect(50, 27, 350, 400); context.stroke();     }
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="shape1" name="round[]" onchange="display()" /> 
<input type="radio" id="shape2" name="round[]" onchange="display()" />

<canvas id="displaycanvas" height="450px" width="820px" style="position:absolute;"> </canvas>
```